# What is the purpose of ため in sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the purpose of ため in 彼は仕事のために彼の車を運転します. I translate it as "As a result of his job, he drives his car."

Comment: http://maggiesensei.com/2019/09/28/how-to-use-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB-tameni/ maybe a good source for you to understand this grammar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[Noun] + の + ために + [Verb]」
>
> 「[Verb 1] + ために + [Verb 2]」

In these sentence patterns, 「ため」 expresses the reason, cause or purpose.

Thus, the sentence:

> 「彼{かれ}は仕事{しごと}のために彼の車{くるま}を運転{うんてん}します。」

means:

> "He drives his car ***for*** his job/work."

FYI: That Japanese sentence is not 100% natural-sounding if I may tell the truth.  We (= native speakers) would generally not use the same pronoun twice in a short sentence like that.  The 「彼の車」 part is what I am referring to.  We would just use 「車」 or 「自分{じぶん}の車」 instead.